# How to use a file that was selected through file dialog?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, filedialog

**My problem is how to use the file I will select with askopenfilename() later on, for example to put it the canvas ?
What should I put instead of the "?" at "Im = ?" ?
Thank you !
Sorry I am very much a beginner**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *



root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1000x690')
root.title("Baccalauréat ISN 2017")

# # #
def Open_Image():
askopenfilename()

# # #
B13= Button(root, text='Open Image', height=5, width= 25, command = askopenfilename)
B13.grid(row=1, column=5, sticky= W + E)

Im = ?
# # #




Nim = Im.resize((int((Im.width*514)/Im.height), 514))   #maxsize =(821, 514) ---> size of the canvas 821-length; 514 -height


nshow = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Nim)

Can = tk.Canvas(root, background = 'blue') 

Can.grid(row = 1, column = 0, rowspan = 6, columnspan = 5, sticky = W + E + N + S)
Cim = Can.create_image(0, 0,  anchor = NW, image = nshow) # "0, 0" space between the picture and the borders

# # #

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to store a file as a variable:

```
    path = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
    os.chdir(path)
    f = open(file_name, mode)
```

mode can be:

'r' - if you want to read data from the file.

'w' - if you want to write data to the file.

You can read the data of the file using the command: `file.read()`.
And write data using the command:  `file.write(data)`(The mode should be accordingly).

Read further in [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python).

Hopefully this will help you,Yahli.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering but 
I do not really get it: where should I fit this inside out of my code ?
I'm really a beginner so.. :)